# Google maps markers dissapear after resume

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hi i am working on an app and the user adds markers my touching points on the map... the issue is that when i press back button and then resume my application the markers are lost .... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly save the point data as json and reload it? Btw you failed to mention which platform and api you're using.

Comment: I managed to save and resume the variable by using SharedPreferences interface... the thing is that i actually need to save the marker as an overlay item created by the given Geopoint and a picture from resources. I don't think is possible to do this so ill just save the point into SharedPreferences into pause and recreate it on resume...thanks for the reply though!! :)

Comment: you still haven't mentioned which api/platform you're using